# javascript: selectize selects the first item by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/selectize.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sifter/0.5.3/sifter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microplugin/0.0.3/microplugin.min.js"></script>            
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/js/selectize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <select id='selecttest'>
            <option value='1'>One</option>
            <option value='2'>Two</option>
            <option value='3'>Three</option>
            <option value='4'>Four</option>
            <option value='5'>Five</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(function($){
        $('#selecttest').selectize({maxItems: 8});
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above displays one by default in select box, I don't want it display anything by default. How can I change this?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan. Thank you bro very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `seletize.js`, you have one property called `items:null`. This will remove the default selected stuff. Also you can use the placeholder for your select field if you want to show anything on default.

```
<div>
    <select id='selecttest' placeholder="select test...">
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
        <option value='3'>Three</option>
        <option value='4'>Four</option>
        <option value='5'>Five</option>
    </select>
</div>

$(function($){
    $('#selecttest').selectize({
        maxItems: 8, 
        items: null
    });
 });
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uZmcD/449/)

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra option with value `""` in select tag. Something like

```
<option value="">Select</option>
```

Check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x3b51fts/8/)